# YouTube search engine box got somehow smaller

Tags: youtube

I have an issue with the search engine box in YouTube! it was like the 1st picture and suddenly now its got smaller like the 2nd picture! the 3rd picture is a video in theater mode the search engine is white and when I type in the text is invisible! any solution?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug on YouTube's side, not on yours. You'll have to wait for them to fix it. You can send feedback to make them aware that you have the issue: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4347644?hl=en

Comment: ok thx for your answer!!